# Checking existence and if exists, is a certain value

Tags: python

I frequently need to check if an instance of a class has a property and if that property exists, make a comparison with its value. Is there no way to do it besides the following?

```
if house.garage:
    if house.garage == '3 car':
        # do something with house.garage
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can "consolidate conditional expression" as outlined by Martin Fowler here: http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/consolidate-conditional-expression#permalink-15

Essentially, any if statement that contains another if statement inside it is really just 1 if statement with an and in between!

```
if house.garage:
    if house.garage == '3 car':
        # do something with house.garage
```

becomes

```
if house.garage and house.garage == '3 car':
    # do something with house.garage
```

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using the dot notation, you can make a call to `getattr`, which can return a default value if the named attribute does not exist:

```
if getattr(house, 'garage', "") == '3 car':
    # proceed
```

If `house` does not have an attribute named 'garage', `getattr` just needs to evaluate to something that does not equal '3 car'.

Comment: People aren't making the distinction between "attribute does not exist" and "attribute has a falsey value", which is very important as the other two answers will raise exceptions if `house.garage` doesn't actually exist as opposed to simply being None.

Comment: This is a good answer, but the other case is more common for me. I typically am checking for foreign keys in a django model. So the attribute always exists (is dotable) but sometimes it is None and will error if I try to access one of the related models attributes.